# Import an HTML file as a Confluence page

Tags: confluence

I have stored some pages that I have created in Confluence (with an account that doesn't exist anymore) as HTML files a while ago.
I would like to use them in another Confluence account. There are often lots of mathematical expressions within the texts so I cannot simply copy the content of the html files and paste them into the Confluence page (right?).

Is there a way to proceed conveniently?

I noticed that the former Confluence pages are stored as folders with multiple files in it which are mainly of the following file formats: `.css` and `.Download`.

screenshot:
[image: img]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

1. log into confluence
2. click on Create
3. click on Import (to the right next to Templates)
4. pick the right option

[image]

More official info here:
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/How-to-Export-Import-Confluence-Pages-and-Spaces-plus-Jira/qaq-p/1022504

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, I can't follow the third step. Where exactly can I find this?

Comment: @Ben I have it as one of the options there, I have added a picture, you might lack permissions and that's why you can see it

Comment: Yeah, seems so. I attached a screenshot of how it looks for me. So, obviously, I'm lacking this option.. well, thanks, though!